# Out of Memory while parsing data in JSON android?

Tags: android, json, dalvik, heap-memory

Hi I am parsing data from JSON. While parsing data I am getting OUT OF MEMORY error and dalvik-heap. How to over come from this problem. and I search in net i didn't found any solution please help me.

Thanks in advance

03-06 08:19:00.618: E/dalvikvm-heap(1415): Out of memory on a 2506782-byte allocation.

```
JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(jsonStr1);

          ArrayList<String> matter1= new ArrayList<String>();

          String stat = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_stat);
          String suc=jsonObj1.getString(TAG_success);

          // Getting JSON Array node
          matter = jsonObj1.getJSONArray(TAG_mdata);

          // looping through All Contacts

          dbdata =new ArrayList<String>();

          for (int i = 0; i < matter.length(); i++) {

              JSONObject j = matter.getJSONObject(i);

              String ddesc= j.getString(TAG_ddesc);
              String spd= j.getString(TAG_sped);
              String gzid=j.getString(TAG_geozid);
              String dev = j.getString(TAG_devid);
              matter1.add(stat);
              matter1.add(suc);

              Log.v("contact", ""+matter1);

              dbdata.add(ddesc);
              dbdata.add(spd);
              dbdata.add(gzid);
              dbdata.add(dev);


              dbdata1.add(dbdata);
```

Comment: delete some dta into your device..

Comment: see my ans bro.hope it work.

Comment: Are you also getting images from server?

Comment: No, getting data from server.

Comment: Are you dealing with images? please post your code. Usually its not the allocation that throws the error but the memory you are using that causes the allocation problem

Comment: I'm not dealing with images..

Comment: It's attempting to allocate 2.5MB in a single chunk.  If that's a string allocation then you have some very large strings.  Can you include the stack trace in your question?

Answer (score 0):

One strange thing about this is that the crash only occurs every 2nd or 3rd time the app is run, leaving me to believe that the memory consumed by the app is not being garbage collected each time the app closes.

That is certainly possible, and if it is the case then it probably due to a memory leak that can be traced back to something that your application is doing. I think you should focus your initial efforts into investigating this aspect ... rather than loading the file in chunks. (I am not familiar with the Android tool-chain, but I am sure it includes memory usage profilers or memory dump analysers.)

EDIT

In response to your followup comment, the fact that it works 2 times in 3 suggests that your app ought to work roughly as-is. Admittedly, you don't have much leeway if the input file gets bigger.

A couple of ideas though:

Rather than reading the file into a String and running the JSON parser on the String, use a parser that can read directly from a stream. Your current solution needs space for two complete copies of the data in memory while you are doing the parsing.

If the file gets much bigger, you may need to think of a design that doesn't create a complete in-memory representation of the data.

I'm not sure that it is a good idea to read a JSON file in "chunks". This could present problems for parsing the JSON ... depending on exactly what you mean by reading in chunks.

Comment: At first time only my app was not opening?

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson library. Will optimize all your process.